# PJSIP - Pjsua2 android: How to add headers while calling?

Tags: android, sip, pjsip, sip-server

Below is my source code for pjsip calling -

```
    String buddy_uri = item.get("uri");

    SipHeaderVector sipHeaderVector = new SipHeaderVector(2);

    SipHeader sipHeader1 = new SipHeader();
    sipHeader1.setHName("Header1");
    sipHeader1.setHValue("Value1");

    SipHeader sipHeader2 = new SipHeader();
    sipHeader.setHName("Header2");
    sipHeader.setHValue("Value2");

    sipHeaderVector.set(0,sipHeader1);
    sipHeaderVector.set(1,sipHeader2);

    MyCall call = new MyCall(account, -1);

    CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam(true);

    SipTxOption sipTxOption = new SipTxOption();
    sipTxOption.setHeaders(sipHeaderVector);
    prm.setTxOption(sipTxOption);

    try {
    call.makeCall(buddy_uri, prm);
} catch (Exception e) {
    call.delete();
    return;
}
```

Above is a code for PJSIP calling by passing custom headers. Unfortunately, authentication is failing as it seems header values are not going in request.

Is above code correct for passing custom headers and their respective values as followed all the documentation of C++ provided by pjsua to pass headers but seems call is not established and asking for some pin which is required on server for authentication via headers.

can some one help???

Answer (score 4):

I'm not using for passing the arguments the `SipTxOption`. Here is my working example that works:

```
    CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam(true);
    SipHeaderVector shv = new SipHeaderVector();
    SipHeader sh = new SipHeader();
    sh.setHName("headerName");
    sh.setHValue("headerValue");

    // add the sip header to the vector
    shv.add(sh);        

    // set headers to the parameter object 
    prm.getTxOption().setHeaders(shv);

    // make call using the desired parameters
    try {
        call.makeCall(buddy_uri, prm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        call.delete();
        return;
    }
```

But in order for the `SipHeaders` to be other party you have to edit the `extensions_macro.conf` to forward the custom headers. You can accomplish this by writing:

```
  exten => s,n,SIPAddHeader(headerName: ${SIP_HEADER(headerName)})
```

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333606/forwarding-x-headers-in-asterisk) thread for some other clarifications.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can confirm this works... Don't forget the 2nd part... Otherwise the header does make its way to the sip server, but most likely wont get passed to the target.